# WCF channel on client timed out different than the set value

Tags: c#, wcf

I have code looks like following (modified) for a WCF client to call a web service via SOAP

```
int operationTimeoutInSeconds = 15;
((IClientChannel)channel).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, operationTimeoutInSeconds);
channel.GetSomeToken();
```

Although the `operationTimeoutInSeconds` is set to 15. From the logs, despite that most of the calls (99%) succeed, I found there are calls timed out after far less than 15 seconds (for example 8 seconds) and there are calls timed out
way longer (for example 50 seconds).

I am wondering what caused time out different than my setting?

Comment: Are you looking at the client logs or the server logs?

Comment: @TomRedfern, client logs. Thx.